# How to convert get(0) in a list as constant and get value

Tags: java, list, constants

`cust` is a list and my list contains only one element. `cust` is required to be a list.

I don't want to hard code `get(0)`. Is there a way I can make constant instead of hard coding `get(0)` all the time?

`cust.get(0).getObjectValue()`.

Comment: If it contains only one element, you don't need a list.

Comment: save it in a Class reference of whatever the getObjectValue returns and just keep using that reference

Comment: @pals you don't need a list if you only have one element. You can store that in an Object reference instead.

Comment: Since this list is common method.. so i dont want to change..

Comment: you can also use `cust.getFirst()` to get the only and lonely element if you are using `linkedlist`. like `list<String> lst=new LinkedList<String>();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use an iterator :

```
cust.iterator().next().getObjectValue();
```

That would work only if your list has at least one element.

Comment: actually it's cust.iterator().next();

Comment: No it's fine to be called many times, unless of course `getObjectValue()` does something really horrible.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = cust.size();
cust.get(size - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info :

Using iterator : (as per @Eran)

```
 Iterator itr = cust.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = itr.next();
 }
```